# Resample weighted group means in data table and show the frequencies of the rank order over all replications

Tags: r, data.table, rank, resampling

I have a dataset (df) with about 3500 observations nested in 11 groups (a:k). My target variable is the Net Promoter Score (nps) which takes one of three values 0, 1 or -1 for each observation/respondent (but essentially the type of target variable should not matter: any numerical variable can be used). Further, the target variable is weighted with the variable "weight".

Following akrun's comment, here is some code to generate sample data:

```
# Function to randomly generate weights
rtnorm <- function(n, mean, sd, a = -Inf, b = Inf){
qnorm(runif(n, pnorm(a, mean, sd), pnorm(b, mean, sd)), mean, sd)
}

# Generate variables
set.seed(7)
nps    <- round(runif(3500, min=-1, max=1), 0) # nps value which takes 1, 0 or -1
group  <- sample(letters[1:11], 3500, TRUE) # groups
weight <- rtnorm(n=3500, mean=1, sd=1, a=0.04, b=16) # weights between 0.04 and 16

# Build data frame
df = data.frame(group, nps, weight)
```

I want to replicate the following steps about 10000 times:

1. Calculate the weighted mean of each group using a sample with replacement of the original dataset. This is easily achieved using data.table:

   ```
   dt_1 <- setDT(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 3500, replace=TRUE),] )[ 
   , .(nps = weighted.mean(nps, w=weight, na.rm = TRUE), # this is the weighted target variable
       N=(.N) # this shows the number of observations drawn for each group as information only  
          ), by = group]
   ```

Note: Intentionally there is no exact number of observations which should be drawn for each group when resampling.

2. Next, I want to know the rank order of the group means:

   ```
   dt_1$rank <- rank(-dt_1$nps, na.last = NA, ties.method= "random")
   ```

Basically, I want to repeat the two steps above 10000 times.

As a result of those 10000 replications I want to create a table which shows for each group (a:k) how many times it turned out to be on rank1, rank2, rank3, …, rank 11 in all 10000 replications.

Basically my desired output should look something like this (I only filled the first column 'a' with numbers, but all groups should show how many times the group mean ranked on which place within the 10000 replications).

```
          a      b      c      d      e      f      g     h
rank1     100    ...   ...    ...    ...    ...    ...   ...
rank2     500    ...
rank3     1000   ...
rank4     1500   ...
rank5     3500   ...
rank6     1500   ...
rank8     1000   ...
rank9     500    ...
rank10    250    ...
rank11    150    ...
```

Any other format would work as well, as long as it shows in how many cases/replications a group took which rank.

I have no idea how to combine the two steps above with the 'replicate' function and how to summarize the results by each group and rank.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can wrap this in a function, then use `replicate` i.e. `replicate(10000, fn, simplify = FALSE)` with arguents and then loop over the `list` and get the table of 'rank' column.  It is better to show a small reproducible example

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I now updated my question inserting some code to produce sample data. I basically understand where you heading, but I have trouble building a complex function like the one you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a function to create the 'rank' column after sampling and then with `replicate`, do the replication of the same `n` times, bind the `list` elements with `rbindlist` and `dcast` into the 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
fdtrank <- function(dat, n1) {
     df1 <- as.data.table(df)
      dt_1 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1), n1, replace = TRUE)]
       dt_1[, .(nps = weighted.mean(nps, w = weight, na.rm = TRUE), N = .N), by = group
            ][, rank := rank(-nps, na.last = NA, ties.method = "random")][]
   }

n <- 10000
lst <- replicate(n, fdtrank(df, 3500), simplify = FALSE)


res <- dcast(rbindlist(lst)[, rank := factor(rank, levels = 1:11, 
   labels = paste0("rank", 1:11))], rank ~ group, length, value.var = "rank")
res
# rank    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k
# 1:  rank1  633  234 2874 1892   23    5  185  747 1426 1050  931
# 2:  rank2  891  401 1767 1625   53   17  360 1020 1482 1167 1217
# 3:  rank3 1079  599 1330 1357   80   32  481 1130 1388 1227 1297
# 4:  rank4 1217  741 1115 1235  126   60  642 1196 1202 1189 1277
# 5:  rank5 1240  974  841 1036  230   84  819 1298 1096 1172 1210
# 6:  rank6 1260 1091  666  909  319  181  992 1244 1028 1142 1168
# 7:  rank7 1202 1292  528  734  528  313 1350 1164  868  989 1032
# 8:  rank8 1066 1485  410  570  808  650 1583  990  695  895  848
# 9:  rank9  818 1565  292  401 1476 1168 1731  732  492  692  633
#10: rank10  449 1097  131  186 2896 2745 1237  363  249  349  298
#11: rank11  145  521   46   55 3461 4745  620  116   74  128   89
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works like a charm!